# Windows Server 2012 R2 - RtkNGUI64.exe System Error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I was using Windows Server 2012 R2 and I uninstalled IIS from the server and restarted. When the machine came back online I logged in and then saw this screen:[image]

Any idea why this is happening or how I can fix it? Nothing happens when I close the screen and I have restarted the machine multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure you only uninstalled IIS? It seems like you’ve somehow removed some DirectX files

Comment: The last thing I did on the machine before I restarted was uninstall IIS and install SSMS and powershell 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Download and reinstall the drivers and support software for your realtek hardware.  Probably Audio, but may be NIC.

You are missing key files.

Comment: How do I go about doing this? This is the screen I see when I log into the system. I'm not sure how I would interact with the system.

Comment: If it's a Dell, click the windows button and type Dell

Comment: That will start a scan for updates.  If it's a Lenovo, then search for Lenovo "system"

Comment: Follw this process for whatever brand device you have, or go to realtec site and find the correct driver for your hardware.  You can also let the system try to find the right driver by giong into Computer Management and right click the device in question and tell it to update driver.